# What does "single-action" mean?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

I know that single-action when used for handguns mean that the gun doesn't have to be cocked in order to fire, but I also saw the phrase "single-action rifle", "single-action shotgun", "single-action submachine gun". I was wondering if "single-action" meant the same thing for all guns, because as far as I know only handguns have to be cocked. After googling, I heard "single-action rifle" meant "bolt-action rifle", is this true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most guns have to be 'cocked', not just handguns. Sub-machine guns, machine guns, rifles, shotguns, all are cocked before use. Example discussion for bolt-action rifles:

> Bolt action is a type of firearm action where the handling of
>   cartridges into and out of the weapon's barrel chamber is operated by
>   manually manipulating the bolt directly via a handle, which is most
>   commonly placed on the right-hand side of the weapon (as most users
>   are right-handed). When the handle is operated, the bolt is unlocked
>   from the receiver and pulled back to open the breech, allowing the
>   spent cartridge case to be extracted and ejected, the firing pin
>   within the bolt is **cocked** (either on opening or closing of the bolt
>   depending on the gun design) and engages the sear, then upon the bolt
>   being pushed back a new cartridge (if available) is loaded into the
>   chamber, and finally the breech is closed tight by the bolt locking
>   against the receiver.

[Bolt Action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolt_action)

Answer (score 0):

You aren't working from an appropriate [definition of "single-action"](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/single-action): *(Firearms, Gunnery, Ordnance & Artillery) (modifier) (of a firearm) requiring the hammer to be cocked by hand before firing*.

Double-action means the trigger both cocks and fires the gun as explained in this [article about the difference between double and single action](https://www.diffen.com/difference/Single_Action_vs_Double_Action).

The difference between a hand gun and a rifle is basically barrel length and the stock on a rifle that allows you to shoulder it. The "action" doesn't matter.

The ["Trigger" article in Everipedia](https://everipedia.org/wiki/lang_en/Trigger_(firearms)) explains what is meant by an "action" when discussing firearms.

> There are numerous types of action, where **action refers to the mechanism (the trigger, hammer, and safeties considered as a unit) or to the logic of how it is built and how it is used**. They are categorized according to which functions the trigger is to perform. In addition to releasing the hammer or the striker, a trigger may cock the hammer or striker, rotate a revolver's cylinder, deactivate passive safeties, select between semi-automatic and full-automatic fire such as the Steyr AUG (see progressive trigger), or pre-set a "set trigger". Most modern firearms use the trigger to deactivate passive safeties but this does not change how they are identified.

Comment: So all guns can be double or single action?

Comment: @VOXuser No, there are different types of firing mechanisms on guns that wouldn't be described as single-action or double-action.

Comment: like which ones?